# pdfplumber and regex - but regex not extracting data and writing to CSV

Tags: python, regex, csv, pdfplumber

Using the following code I am able to obtain the list of transactions in the desired format

```
import re
import pdfplumber
import csv


line_re = re.compile(r"(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s+\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}.+)$")


transactions = []

with pdfplumber.open('./Bank Acct statement.pdf') as pdf:
    for page in pdf.pages:
        
        text = page.extract_text()

        
        lines = text.split('\n')

        for line in lines:
            if re.match(line_re, line):
                transactions.append(line)
```

The above returns the following list of transactions:

```
26/01/2023 26/01/2023 Payment Received Z Kona 8 000.00 8 085.87
26/01/2023 26/01/2023 Banking App Payment: Sihle -2 000.00 6 085.87
26/01/2023 26/01/2023 Payment Fee -1.50 6 084.37
26/01/2023 26/01/2023 SMS Payment Notification Fee -0.25 6 084.12
26/01/2023 26/01/2023 Payment Received Z Kona 15 000.00 21 084.12
26/01/2023 26/01/2023 Payment Received Z Kona 1 500.00 22 584.12
26/01/2023 26/01/2023 Payment Received Z Kona 2 000.00 24 584.12
26/01/2023 26/01/2023 Banking App Transfer to Ms K Savings (1816578655) -18 500.00 6 084.12
```

However when trying to extract the components and writing to csv, the csv file is empty. This is the modified code where I try and do the entire process:

```
import re
import pdfplumber
import csv


line_re = re.compile(r"(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\s+\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}.+)$")


transactions = []

with pdfplumber.open('./Bank Acct statement.pdf') as pdf:
    for page in pdf.pages:
       
        text = page.extract_text()

       
        lines = text.split('\n')

        for line in lines:
            if re.match(line_re, line):
                
                transactions.append(line)

# Define headers for the CSV file
csv_headers = [
    "Posting Date",
    "Transaction Date",
    "Description",
    "Amount",
    "Balance",
]

# Specify the CSV file path
csv_file_path = "transactions.csv"

# Write transactions to the CSV file
with open(csv_file_path, mode="w", newline="") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    
    # Write the headers as the first row
    csv_writer.writerow(csv_headers)
    
    # Write each transaction as a row in the CSV file
    for transaction in transactions:
        # Split the transaction line into its components
        match = re.search(
            r"(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+([\w\s\(\),]+)\s+(-?\d{1,10}\s\d{1,2}\.\d{2})\s+(-?\d{1,10}\s\d{1,2}\.\d{2})",
            transaction,
        )
        if match:
            csv_writer.writerow([match.group(1), match.group(2), match.group(3), match.group(4), match.group(5)])

print(f"Transactions saved to {csv_file_path}")
```

The CSV only returns the headers, and all text in the first column. What am I doing wrong? I am not the best at regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is empty because your pattern does not match.

I have added named capture groups for clarity, your updated pattern could be:

```
^(?P<posting_date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(?P<transaction_date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(?P<description>[\w\s(),:]+?)\s+(?P<Amount>-?\d{1,3}(?:\s\d{3})*\.\d{2})\s+(?P<Balance>-?\d{1,3}(?:\s\d{3})*\.\d{2})$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?P<posting_date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+` Match a date like pattern
- `(?P<transaction_date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+` Same pattern for the transaction date
- `(?P<description>[\w\s(),:]+?)\s+` Match the allowed characters, as few as possible
- `(?P<Amount>-?\d{1,3}(?:\s\d{3})*\.\d{2})\s+` Match the amount ending on `.` and 2 digits with a whitespace char between 3 digits and leading 1-3 digits
- `(?P<Balance>-?\d{1,3}(?:\s\d{3})*\.\d{2})` Same pattern for the balance
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ol6bmn/1).

The updated part of the code:

```
match = re.search(
    r"(?P<posting_date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(?P<transaction_date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(?P<description>[\w\s(),:]+?)\s+(?P<Amount>-?\d{1,3}(?:\s\d{3})*\.\d{2})\s+(?P<Balance>-?\d{1,3}(?:\s\d{3})*\.\d{2})$",
    transaction,
)
```

The content of the `transactions.csv` file:

```
Posting Date,Transaction Date,Description,Amount,Balance
26/01/2023,26/01/2023,Payment Received Z Kona,8 000.00,8 085.87
26/01/2023,26/01/2023,Banking App Payment: Sihle,-2 000.00,6 085.87
26/01/2023,26/01/2023,Payment Fee,-1.50,6 084.37
26/01/2023,26/01/2023,SMS Payment Notification Fee,-0.25,6 084.12
26/01/2023,26/01/2023,Payment Received Z Kona,15 000.00,21 084.12
26/01/2023,26/01/2023,Payment Received Z Kona,1 500.00,22 584.12
26/01/2023,26/01/2023,Payment Received Z Kona,2 000.00,24 584.12
26/01/2023,26/01/2023,Banking App Transfer to Ms K Savings (1816578655),-18 500.00,6 084.12
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for the informative regex pattern. Like I said I am not the best at regex. For anyone in future herewith final code used to extract all transactions.

```
import pdfplumber
import re
import csv

# Define the PDF file path
pdf_file_path = './Bank Acct statement.pdf'

# Define the regex pattern to capture the data
line_re = re.compile(r"(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} .+? (-?\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*\.\d{2}) -?\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*\.\d{2})")

# Create an empty list to store the extracted data
data = []

# Open the PDF file with pdfplumber
with pdfplumber.open(pdf_file_path) as pdf:
    for page in pdf.pages:
        # Extract text from the page
        text = page.extract_text()

        # Search for the pattern in the text and extract matches
        matches = re.findall(line_re, text)

        # Process the matches and append to the data list
        for match in matches:
            data.append(match[0])

# Define the output file path
output_file_path = 'output_data.csv'

# Write the data to the output file
with open(output_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as outfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(outfile)

    # Write the header row
    csvwriter.writerow(["Posting Date", "Transaction Date", "Description", "Amount", "Balance"])

    for transaction in data:
        match = re.search(
            r"(?P<posting_date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(?P<transaction_date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})\s+(?P<description>[\w\s(),:]+?)\s+(?P<Amount>-?\d{1,3}(?:\s\d{3})*\.\d{2})\s+(?P<Balance>-?\d{1,3}(?:\s\d{3})*\.\d{2})$",
            transaction,
        )

        if match:
            csvwriter.writerow([match.group("posting_date"), match.group("transaction_date"),
                                match.group("description"), match.group("Amount"), match.group("Balance")])

print(f"Data extracted and written to {output_file_path}")
```